# How to make a Matplotlib animated violinplot?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am trying to animate a violinplot, so I have started off with something I think should be very basic, but it is not working.  I think the problem is that violinplot doesn't accept set_data, but I don't otherwise know how to pass the changing data to violinplot.  For this example I would like a plot where the mean slowly shifts to higher values.  If I am barking up the wrong tree, please advise on a code which does work to animate violinplot.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.animation as animation


fig, ax = plt.subplots()
data = np.random.rand(100)

def animate(i):
    v.set_data(data+i)  # update the data
    return v

v = ax.violinplot([])
ax.set_ylim(0,200)

v_ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, animate, np.arange(1, 200), 
                              interval=50, blit=True)
```

Answer (score 4):

Indeed, there is no set_data method for the violinplot. The reason is probably, that there is a lot of calculations going on in the background when creating such a plot and it consists of a lot of different elements, which are hard to update.

The easiest option would be to simply redraw the violin plot and not use blitting.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.animation as animation


fig, ax = plt.subplots()
data = np.random.normal(loc=25, scale=20, size=100)

def animate(i, data):
    ax.clear()
    ax.set_xlim(0,2)
    ax.set_ylim(0,200)
    data[:20] = np.random.normal(loc=25+i, scale=20, size=20)
    np.random.shuffle(data)
    ax.violinplot(data)

animate(0)

v_ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, animate, np.arange(1, 200), 
                              fargs=(data,), interval=50, blit=False)

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Just what I was going to do. I don't really *know* what's idiomatic, but my hunch is that it might be better to pass all the `data` as additional `fargs` in `FuncAnimation` (and picking from that based on `i`) rather than pulling them in from the global namespace. I'd also note that `violinplot()` returns a dict full of artists, so the return value can't have any non-dict methods.

Comment: I wouldn't see any reason for not using global in this case; I can only see the danger that people might copy it to some other use case and experience problems there; however I assume this is true for many constructs you find in simple examples. But because you asked for it, I edited the code.

Comment: Concerning the returned dictionary, that is simply a question of design. One could have decided not to return a dictionary but some other kind of Collection which would allow for possessing an update method. It's simply not designed to be updated, that's all.

Comment: Yeah, of course, it's by design. But just by looking at the return value one should clearly not expect anything like `.set_data`. And I mostly noted the global thing because it's probably faster to do a local namespace lookup, considering that animations typically have a lot of steps. It was obviously perfectly fine as it was.

Comment: can we animate the same in Seaborn ?

Comment: Yes, a violinplot in seaborn is created via `seaborn.violinplot`.

Comment: PSA for people using JupyterNotebook: Change the backend as follows ``%matplotlib notebook`` - else the animation won't work